# How can I repair my Bosch dishwasher that won't drain?

Tags: repair, appliances, dishwasher

My Bosch dishwasher stopped draining. At the end of the cycle, it gets stuck at 1 minute remaining. When I open the door, there's water that hasn't drained.

Here's what I've tried:

Following the instructions from a [video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Oq-nTnyh6A), I emptied the water, removed the cover on the drain pump impeller, removed any additional water and debris, took out the back flow preventer, and removed additional water and debris.

After doing this, the first two times I ran the dishwasher it did not fill with any water.

I then poured some water into the bottom of the dishwasher to see if it would drain and started another cycle. This time, it did fill with additional water, but I'm back to the original problem. It doesn't drain at the end, and it gets stuck at showing 1 minute remaining.

Photo with drain pump impeller cover removed:

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from your picture. Is there a float switch in this unit that is sticking in the down position?

Comment: Is your dishwasher connected to the garbage disposal without an air gap or a high point in the tube (above garbage disposal)?  Could you be sucking in food or debris that is clogging the exhaust line from the dishwasher?

Comment: If the timer isn't advancing, it might not be the drain at all - so check your dial too. Also check for items (like a bobbie pin) in the impeller.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the system? Most of these have some button combo which will reset the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some large particles in there & it seems that you're running out of time before a complete draining. You likely have a partially blocked drain line from the sink side of things. Make sure your drain hose is clear to the sink drain or disposer & that your sink-top Air Gap (if you have one) is clean.

Your drain hose should enter the sink cabinet at the very top & your hose should be angled up from the sink drain or disposer inlet with no sag or dip below the top of that inlet to avoid any future clogs. You should be good to go after that's all squared away.

Comment: I had this exact problem and, after buying a new dishwasher, I realized the Sink-top air gap was clogged. D'oh! Easy fix, but I didn't know to even check it.

Comment: Yeah, I hate Air Gap Fixtures, the dumbest crap ever. They completely kill the dishwasher's draining pressure, which is significant. I've only done a dozen dishwasher installs or re-installs and never had a single or slightest problem by creating the Air Gap with the dishwasher's drain line (see above). In fact, on 3 re-installs I cleared the old line with the dishwasher discharge...popped the garbage disposal's gunk right out and scrubbed it clean. Air Gaps are required, but Air Gap Fixtures are not, thankfully.